# What is wrong with my Cordon Apple tree?

Tags: tree-care, pest-control

It has a white spider web like covering...
What is it and how should I treat it?
I live in the UK.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If it doesn't wash off, maybe it's trichromes.

Comment: It looks like woolly aphid